# Resolving properties bi-directionally across two files

Tags: java, ant, build

Imagine I have an ant build system which loads various property files.  Sometimes properties declared in one file are used in the value of properties declared in another.

For example:

```
File 1:
java.version=1.6

File 2:
jdk.path=/blah/foo/java/${java.version}
```

This works fine if I load file 1 before file 2.  In some cases, however, the substitution needs to happen in the reverse order - things declared in file 2 will be used by file 1.

It's not possible to combine these files due to external constraints and the design of the system.

Is there some way to implement the bi-directional expansion?  Maybe some way to post-process the properties and apply additional expansion steps?  You may assume that there are no circular dependencies in the expansion chains.

Comment: I'd suggest writing a custom task for aggregeting such properties in one file, and then including resulting file in the main task

Comment: That won't work either, since even within a file resolution is subject to the order in which variables appear in the file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Interestingly the following seems to work:

File test1:

```
a1=a1
a2=${b1}
a3=${b3}
```

File test2:

```
b1=b1
b2=${a1}
b3=${a2}
```

Ant:

```
<!-- Repeat until result is fully resolved. -->
<var file="test1"/>
<var file="test2"/>
<!-- a3 = ${b3} -->
<var file="test1"/>
<var file="test2"/>
<!-- a3 = ${b1} -->
<var file="test1"/>
<var file="test2"/>
<!-- a3 = b1 -->
<echo>${a3}</echo>
```

Comment: I understood what you were saying. That doesn't change the fact that I tried that *first* and just got ${b3} continuously in my own example. Perhaps it's a different version of ANT or something, but I do believe if it works on yours it's a bug. If you read the documentation (http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/property.html) it says `Properties are immutable: whoever sets a property first freezes it for the rest of the build; they are most definitely not variables.`

Comment: I'm confused, were you talking to yourself there?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. The answer works fine. @AlexK just thought that you could do a similar approach but using <property> instead of <var>, but according to ant rules properties can't be changed. As long as you use <var>s your fine, you can then place them in to properties afterwards I guess, but there's no need.